# WSO2 Identity Server 5.0.0 clustering with Oracle Coherence

Tags: wso2, identity, hazelcast, oracle-coherence, jcache

Halo everybody (maybe Asela? :),

Can anyone guide me how can I implement Oracle Coherence as a Cache provider with WSO2 Identity Server 5.0.0 clustered using with WSO2 ELB?

I found some very useful links on that topic, from which I consider this one as a good start: [Clustering Identity Server](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER420/Clustering+Identity+Server)

But I cannot find a way how to find solution for changing Hazelcast cache provider for any other provider.

I also realized, WSO2 is not using javax.caching implementation from JDK (since it was introduced in 1.7 and later), it is using its own based on JSR-107 (from which JSR I suppose Java JDK JCache is originated.

This article shows, that there is a way, how to somehow implement user JSR 107 JCache, but I don't see it configured for whole Identity Server:
[WSO2 Multi-tenant Cache: JSR-107 (JCache)](http://blog.afkham.org/2013/11/wso2-multi-tenant-cache-jsr-107-jcache.html)

I'm expecting answer which will guide me, what to change or add (for instance to  carbon core) and where to setup / configure those changes, to make them global used within WSO2 Identity Server 5.0.0.

I hope it is relevant question and since this Carbon based platform is very rich and configurable, I hope this will be possible with some time invested.

Thank you in advance,

Josef

Answer (score 0):

Coherence supports the real JCache APIs, so if WSO2 uses JCache, it should be easy to integrate Coherence!

Comment: Have you ever tried to change something in WSO2? :) In this case some help will be nice. Trust me.

Comment: There's a presentation by Brian Oliver (JCache spec lead) on youtube showing the Coherence JCache capability: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ejwA904VnDg ... there's documentation here: http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/coherence/develop-applications/jcache_intro.htm#COHDG5778 ... and a tutorial here: http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/coherence/develop-applications/jcache_example.htm#COHDG5789

Comment: You have problably haven't got what I was trying to ask for. It is maybe I'm not native English speaker so I might have used wrong words. 

So - I need help with integration Coherence into WSO2. I.e. how to implement &configure Coherence helper classes.

I don't need help with Coherence itself. This I can handle by myself (I guess) using links you provided and which I have already known. Anyway, thank you for your effort.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know much about the internals of WSO2.